# Centered text besides a figure

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to make a tile page like the attached figure, but I don't know how to center the text (according to the page) besides a  figure placed at its top-right. I write the code below, but the title will under the figure.

```
\begin{flushleft}
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\textbf{}Number:1234567890} \hfill
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=180pt]{lion.pdf}}
\end{flushleft}

 \begin{center}
 {\Large First line of a long title}
 \vspace{10pt}
 {\Large Second line of the title}
 \vspace{10pt}
 {\Large Third line of the long title}
 \end{center}
```

Could you help me? 
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMbZw.jpg)

Comment: A few notes regarding your code. To set something in boldface, use `\textbf{...the text...}` or `{\bfseries ...the text...}`. Your version, `\textbf{}` will do nothing, since there is nothing between the braces. In your `center` environment, the three lines will be set as a single one, since there is no linebreak. The `\vspace`s do not split the line and will end up *below* the text. Finally, if I understand you correctly, you want to have the three lines of the title beside the lion. However, the `center` environment will go to a new line below the other material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you write, in plain text and in (La)TeX, it is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve. Here is a first interpretation (well, in fact the second, since I deleted the first one). Feel free to tell me what should be different. Modify `5ex` to shift the title lines up and down in relation to the image. Increasing `1.8cm` shifts the image down in relation to the number on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{1234567890}
\hfill
\raisebox{-1.8cm}[0ex][5ex]%
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}}

\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries
First line of a long title\\
Second line of the title\\
Third line of the long title
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with your code, I think I can figure out what I need.